# Reducing costs for setting up marine aquarium

Tags: fish, aquarium

I live close to the Baltic Sea which is part of Atlantic ocean. I am planning to set up marine aquarium, but found that it costy, does being close to the sea and collecting all needed inhabitants right from the sea would reduce prices?

Answer (score 3):

Not likely. The equipment costs are going to be relatively the same which are a huge portion of the cost. In your case, the baltic is a temperate / cold water environment, and these types of aquariums are usually more expensive than the standard tropical ones. You'll likely need a chiller to keep the water temperature low enough, and stocking in cold water tanks is difficult.

Also, I don't know the water quality of the ocean in your area, but most ocean water collected directly on the coast is often unsuitable for an aquarium. Heavy metal and other contaminants are very common and typically do not work well in a closed home aquarium environment.

The best way to keep costs down is through careful planning and stocking. As far as coral tanks go, not keeping SPS or other coral that require very clean, lower nutrient, water is the best option for keeping costs down in a reef tank. Limited stocking can reduce the need for a skimmer and reduce the need to do frequent water changes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What if I would be close to the Mediterranean sea which is tropical, would it have any advantage in that case?